# Does a double negative itself convey a positive meaning?

Tags: double-negation

Does a double negative itself **convey** a positive meaning on its own? Or do we just **infer** a positive meaning by a double negative?

Comment: I don't have no answer to that, but please explore the many "related" questions in the panel on the right, which were previously asked.

Comment: Do you have an example sentence that you think has a double negative that does not itself convey a positive meaning but for which we would infer one anyway?